# Create function which parse an Enum in C#

Tags: c#

I know that to parse a string to specific `enum` like:

```
enum AnEnumType 
{
   TEST_,
   OTHER_TEST_,
   OTHERS_
}

enum OtherEnumType 
{
   TEST1_,
   OTHER_TEST1_,
   OTHERS1_
}


string aValueString = "TEST_";

AnEnumType result = (AnEnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnEnumType), aValueString);
```

So, I want to create a function, a generic one which use parser for my `enum`(s) like:

```
public Type ConvertStringToAnEnum(string value, Type anyType){

return (anyType)Enum.Parse(typeof(anyType), aValueString);
}
```

But I guess that is not OK...

How to make the function which parse any enumeration type specified as argument in function?

like I want to call `OtherEnumType result = ConvertStringToAnEnum("TEST1_", OtherEnumType)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the generic method generic:

```
public T ConvertStringToAnEnum<T>(string value){
  return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

Usage:

```
OtherEnumType result = ConvertStringToAnEnum<OtherEnumType>("TEST1_");
```

Comment: you were faster, +1 for you :)

Comment: Important: It's not type safe because `T` is not required to be a enum.

Comment: Maybe [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) would be a better option?

Comment: @FelixK. I will use the function as private...The function won't be public

Comment: @FelixK.: Not strictly true. It's type safe, but not strictly typed. Using it with a non enum gives you an exception. Besides `Enum.Parse(typeof(int), "asdf")` also compiles just fine...

Comment: @Guffa: How about `public T ConvertStringToAnEnum<T>(string value) where T : enum`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: That would be nice if it worked. The keyword `enum` is not identified as a type, and you can't use the type `Enum` for a constraint.

Comment: @Guffa: Then what would be the next best option to write after `T:??` so that we can constrain it to take enum only?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use

```
public T ConvertStringToAnEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

With this you can do
`OtherEnumType tp2 = ConvertStringToAnEnum<OtherEnumType>("TEST1_");`

or using an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
    }
}
```

With this you can do

```
OtherEnumType tp2 = "TEST1_".ToEnum<OtherEnumType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how involved you want to get, you can also use attributes to give your enum values more descriptive names. [Associating Strings with enums in C#](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/associating-strings-with-enums-in-c) gives a pretty good intro in how to do this.